# Minio does not start on 2 nodes, no informative error

Tags: docker-compose, minio

I tried to run minimal config on 2 nodes with 4 disks in each with this [docker-compose](https://pastebin.com/nPBVDt3t) file.

It ouputs first this:

```
Recreating minio ... done
Attaching to minio
minio    | 
minio    | API: SYSTEM()
minio    | Time: 07:32:37 UTC 05/18/2023
minio    | Error: WARNING: Expected number of all hosts (2) to be remote +1 (2) (*errors.errorString)
minio    |        5: internal/logger/logger.go:258:logger.LogIf()
minio    |        4: cmd/peer-rest-client.go:781:cmd.newPeerRestClients()
minio    |        3: cmd/notification.go:1099:cmd.NewNotificationSys()
minio    |        2: cmd/server-main.go:278:cmd.initAllSubsystems()
minio    |        1: cmd/server-main.go:541:cmd.serverMain()
```

Then spams this:

```
minio    | API: SYSTEM()
minio    | Time: 07:32:40 UTC 05/18/2023
minio    | Error: Read failed. Insufficient number of drives online (*errors.errorString)
minio    |        6: internal/logger/logger.go:258:logger.LogIf()
minio    |        5: cmd/prepare-storage.go:245:cmd.connectLoadInitFormats()
minio    |        4: cmd/prepare-storage.go:305:cmd.waitForFormatErasure()
minio    |        3: cmd/erasure-server-pool.go:107:cmd.newErasureServerPools()
minio    |        2: cmd/server-main.go:783:cmd.newObjectLayer()
minio    |        1: cmd/server-main.go:609:cmd.serverMain()
minio    | Waiting for a minimum of 4 drives to come online (elapsed 3s)
```

When I launched single host it ran perfectly. As I get it from docs, multi-node cluster with 2 nodes and 4 disks is not reliable but at least has to work.